# Add custom reference style Microsoft Office 2010 Home & Student

Tags: microsoft-office, styles

I'm following [this site](http://bibword.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Styles&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Installation) to install a custom reference style on Office 2010.

The problem is my version does not have the folder `\Bibliography\Style` where the site says it should be. Where do this folder is? Do I have any other way to add my custom style to office?

Comment: which version of office 2010? I know for a fact it works on H&S and up... if its starter, it dosen't support references at all

Comment: Where did you look? Maybe your office is installed at an alternative location?

Comment: My office is at default location and I have Home&Student 2010 version. A friend found the path on H&S 2007 and on Office 2010 Professional, but I can't seen to find it on my version=(

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still interested. I think there are two paths:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography\Style

**Since Office 2013:**
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style.